# I need a single Regex pattern which can help me extract the specified substrings from the given strings when using REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheets

Tags: string, google-sheets, substring, delimiter

I have a set of three strings as shown below:

```
GarnetUniversity_Zeus_Cronos_Greece_675|GoNow-New-Image-0S
SnoxUniversity_Dionysus_Zeus_Crete-50_450|GoNow-New-Image-DS
OwlUniversity_Athena_Zeus_Athens3476_675|GoNow-New-Image-0S
```

I was told to find a regex pattern that can extract the given substrings as follows:

```
Greece
Crete-50
Athens3476
```

I first tried using the pattern "*(\w+-\w+)*" and the results came out as follows:

```
#N/A
Dionysus_Zeus_Crete-50
#N/A
```

Then I tried using the pattern "*(.*)*" and this was the result:

```
Zeus_Cronos_Greece
Dionysus_Zeus_Crete-50
Athena_Zeus_Athens3476
```

I tried several more attempts but none have given me the exact value of the substrings that I am looking for. Can anyone give me a regex pattern that can give me the exact substrings that I had initially specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:(.*)_){4}")
```

Or without REGEX:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"_"),,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(regexextract(A:A,"([^_]*)_\d+")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXREPLACE` instead of `REGEXEXTRACT`

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ".+_([^_]+)_\d.+", "$1")
```